# Как узнать цвет символа, который находится в строке i, в колонке k, в RichEdit?

Tags: delphi

Как узнать цвет символа, который находится в строке i, в колонке k, в RichEdit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте выделить символ и просмотреть аттрибут [SelAttributes](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/ComCtrls.TCustomRichEdit.SelAttributes)

```
  with richedit.SelAttributes do
  begin
      SomeColor := Color;
  end;
```

Comment: Но мне нужно что бы пользователь не выделял. Это будет что-то как автоматическая подсветка синтаксиса.

Comment: Код (а не пользователь) может выделять сам, а потом снимать выделение.

Comment: Но мне нужно что бы при нажатии на клавише код не выделялся, иначе просто когда юзер нажмёт ещё раз, на другую кнопку, то всё содержимое удалится :(

Answer (score 1):

richedit имеет свойство HideSelection - попробуйте его использовать с True.

```
richedit1.HideSelection:=True;
```

Теперь выделение не будет показано. Возможно, этого хватит для ваших нужд

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]